# pm-suspend prevents me from turning the computer on in any way

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, ipmi

Ubuntu Server 18.04 with all of the standard configurations from apt upgrade.  No custom kernels or anything out of the ordinary.

- SUPERMICRO MBD-X10SL7-F-O
- i3-4160
- 16GB ECC
- various disks for use as a NAS

I previously used `pm-suspend` and `wakeonlan $MAC_ADDRESS` in the past successfully to suspend and resume.  This was a while ago (1year+)

Today I tried to do this again and the computer went into suspend mode and never recovered.  I tried the IPMI interface with my supermicro board to restart the server, unsuccessful.  I tried to pull the plug and wait then power it on, unsuccessful.  There is a blinking power button even after doing a hard power cycle with the PSU.  Should I try to remove the battery to reset the motherboard? I don't want to lose all of my configurations if those aren't permanently saved.

Any advice? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Does the IPMI respond at all when you send it commands like `ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IP ADDRESS> -U username -P password chassis fru print`?  If after a full hard power cycle by pulling the PSU and if you can pressing the power button a few times without any power connected, then you possibly have a bad motherboard, CPU, RAM, etc.  Maybe try stripping down hardware items from the board and trying to power on after each item is removed.  Or try swapping parts around on the board to see if that helps.

Comment: I don't use the command line tool from my workstation, but I do have access to the IPMI web interface.  I added a screenshot of the FRU info.  I also tried pulling the CMOS battery and the computer still won't start, but I no longer have the blinking light on the power button.  It's so weird that everything was working fine since 2016 with basically 24/7 operation and now all of a sudden a software change led to hardware failure?

Comment: I wasn't really after the FRU, but more of checking to see if it is responding to those commands.  Usually that is a good sign that the system is getting proper power to it.  The BMC/IPMI is its own thing that works independent.  That is strange that everything was working, but you never know especially with server hardware.  While it is designed to be powered on for extended periods of time without the need to restart, etc, there are times that the system may actually go belly up even during restarts.  I have worked around many SuperMicro systems in the data centers that I have worked in.

Comment: I swapped the power supply and was able to turn on the motherboard.  I haven't connected all of the drives back up, but that was definitely the issue.  I wonder if the pm-suspend command triggered something in the PSU?

Comment: I don't know if it was the command, or more possibly that the power supply was just hanging on a thread and when the motherboard dropped to a lower power mode, it also dropped the power supply and it stopped working possibly losing a 12V power rail.  My desktop at home has 2 power supplies on it, and my lower power supply went bad during a reboot of the host and would no longer stay on.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experiences.  The PSU to fail was a Seasonic G-550 80 Plus Gold.